# Remove characters with pattern from a tab-delimited file

Tags: unix, awk, sed, programming-pearls

I have saveral files with pattern such as

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| NODE_1_length_59711_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_1 | 12.8 |
| NODE_1_length_59711_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_2 | 18.9 |
| NODE_2_length_59711_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_1 | 14.3 |
| NODE_2_length_59711_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_2 | 16.1 |
| NODE_165433_length_59711_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_1 | 29 |

I want to remove all characters from starting '1' to last '_'. so that I can get an output like this from multiple files-

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1_1 | 12.8 |
| 1_2 | 18.9 |
| 2_1 | 14.3 |
| 2_2 | 16.1 |
| 165433_1 | 29 |

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: `echo 'NODE_165433_length_59711_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_1' | sed -E 's/^NODE_([0-9]+)_.*_([0-9]+)/\1_\2/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -F "\t" '{ fld1=gensub(/(^NODE_)([[:digit:]]+)(.*)([[:digit:]]+$)/,"\\2_\\4","g",$1);OFS=IFS;print fld1"\t"$2}' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F "\t" '{                                                       # Set the field separator to tab
               fld1=gensub(/(^NODE_)([[:digit:]]+)(.*)([[:digit:]]+$)/,"\\2_\\4","g",$1);                                      # Split the first field into 4 sections represented in parenthesis and then substitute the line for the the second section, a "_" and then the fourth section. Read the result into a variable fld1
               print fld1"\t"$2                                      # Print fld1, followed by a tab and then the second field.
             }' file
```

Answer (score 2):

### [see demo](https://regex101.com/r/BTcCPo/1)

```
echo 'NODE_165433_length_59711_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_1' | sed -E 's/^NODE_([0-9]+)_.*_([0-9]+)/\1_\2/'
```

**Output:**

```
165433_1
```